# ATS key NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent behaviour on iOS 10

Tags: xcode, ios9, ios10

If I compile an app with iOS 9 and loads it on iOS 10 then does ATS key NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent works on iOS 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work regardless of compiled version. NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent will work on iOS 10, but will get ignored on iOS 9.